# Save downloaded files in folder (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, loops, automation, shutil

I have the following code. When the inner loop has finished (breaks), I want the downloaded files to be placed in a specific folder. I want this to be done for every time the loop gets executed and the exception is reached. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
#Function to export data
def loop_function():

    #Search client
    searchCustomerButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ibSearchPatient"]')
    searchCustomerButton.click()    

    #Loop client ID's
    followLoop = range(0, 10)
    for x in followLoop:
        xpath = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid_Patienten_ctl00__'
        xpath += str(x)
        xpath += '"]/td[3]'
        
        #Click on cliënt ID
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

        #Click on Zorgtraject
        zorgtrajectButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
        zorgtrajectButton.click()

        #Loop Zorgtraject ID's
        followLoop2 = range(0,10)
        for x in followLoop2:
            try:
                xpath2 = '//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_RadGrid1_ctl00__'
                xpath2 += str(x)
                xpath2 += '"]/td[2]'

                #Click on Zorgtraject ID
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2).click()

                #Dossier button
                dossierButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span/span')
                dossierButton.click()

                #Dropdown select
                dropdownSelector = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_Arrow"]')
                dropdownSelector.click()

                #Prevent not interactable error
                time.sleep(1)

                #Select 50
                selectDropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox_DropDown"]/div/ul/li[4]')
                selectDropdown.click()

                #Load files to be downloaded
                time.sleep(1)

                #Check all documents
                tickDossier = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_radGridBehandelVerloop_ctl00_ctl02_ctl01_headerChkboxPrint"]')
                tickDossier.click()

                #Click print
                printButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_btnPrintBehandelverloop"]')
                printButton.click()

                #Click on Zorgtraject ID
                zorgtrajectButton2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Top_ToolBar_MenuCurrentPage"]/div/ul/li[3]/a/span/span/span')
                zorgtrajectButton2.click()

            #If no Zorgtraject ID, start function over
            except NoSuchElementException:
                src = 'C:\\Users\\sohan\\Downloads'
                dst = 'C:\\Users\\sohan\\Documents\\Werk\\BIA Solutions\\Huid & Laserkliniek Delft\\Data\\'
                
                testLoop = range(1, 10)
                for i in testLoop:
                    dst = dst + str(i)

                    files = [i for i in os.listdir(src) if i.startswith("behandel") and path.isfile(path.join(src, i))]
                    for f in files:
                        shutil.move(path.join(src, f), dst)

                #Search client
                searchCustomerButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ibSearchPatient"]')
                searchCustomerButton.click() 
                break

loop_function()
```

Comment: I see no downloaded files there...

Comment: `#Click print
                printButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_btnPrintBehandelverloop"]')
                printButton.click()`

This code downloads a pdf file.

Comment: OK, it downloads the file to default / predefined directory. Now you want to copy that file to some other location? What is the download files path defined in your project? Where do you wish to move that files?

Comment: I wish to move the files to a different folder each time. For example: if the loop has executed the first time, I want the files in 'Downloads' to be moved to folder '1'. If the loop is executed the second time, the 'Downloads' folder should be empty. Then I want all the files in downloads to be moved to folder '2'.

I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks for thinking along with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download the file by your code with

```
printButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_CPH_Main_ctl00_Verslagen_btnPrintBehandelverloop"]') 
printButton.click()`
```

it downloads the file to the downloads folder you defined in your driver options.
Let's say the default folder is `C:/Downloads` and you want to move the files to folder `C:/Folder1`
Let's say each your downloaded file starts with "my_file"

What you have to do is:

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil

src = `C:/Downloads`
dst = `C:/Folder1`

files = [i for i in os.listdir(src) if i.startswith("my_file") and path.isfile(path.join(src, i))]
for f in files:
    shutil.move(path.join(src, f), dst)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I want all the files to be deleted after being copied, so for the second loop the files from the first loop aren't copied again too. How could I do this? Could the files also be cut and pasted?

Comment: Sorry, you should use `move` instead of `copy` to remove the files from the original folder. Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks! I have this code now (see updated code). But now the downloads don't show up in 'Downloads', but neither in the folders. Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hm... I think you should debug that to see where are files going to now. I can't see this from my place..

Comment: With the current code, all the files get pasted into folder '1', is doesn't seem to increment the path, I think? But how to fix this?

Comment: Sure, you should update the destination folder dynamically

Comment: You can define dst = `C:/Folder` and inside the loop redefine it like this: dst = dst + i  where i is the index

Comment: With the code I have now, all the files are still pasted into folder '1'... Any clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: As I mentioned before, you can define `dst = C:/Folder` before, out of the loops. Now, inside the loop you have a `x` index. So you can dynamically build the destination folder inside the loop as `dst = dst + str(x+1)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand what you mean. Could you maybe give an example of what you mean? I thought I implemented what you said in your previous comment.

Comment: I see you defined destination folder as `dst = 'C:\\Users\\sohan\\Documents\\Werk\\BIA Solutions\\Huid & Laserkliniek Delft\\Data\\'`  just add index there like this: `dst = 'C:\\Users\\sohan\\Documents\\Werk\\BIA Solutions\\Huid & Laserkliniek Delft\\Data' +str(x+1) + '\\'`. That's it!

Comment: Thank you so much again!! This worked!! I really appreciate your help!